# creating a tarball, encrypt it on the fly and keeps tar messages in a log file

Tags: bash, shell, tar, gnupg, tee

On OSX I'm trying to create a tarball of a directory and on the fly encrypt
it with gpg and keeps the output of the tar messages in a log file for
later analysis.

While the tar+gpg on the fly it's pretty easy

```
tar zcvf - foo | gpg -e -r foo@bar.com -o foo.tgz.gpg
```

so far I'm failing to log the output of tar (and maybe the gpg one in
case) to a log file.

I tried several combination of

```
tar | gpg | tee
tar | gpg 2>&1 >(tee)
tar | gpg > file.log
```

any help here?

Cheers
Davide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2> file.log` should achieve it.
If you want to `tee` the `stderr` stream and also keep it going to the original destination, you can achieve that with

`2> >(tee file.log >&2)`

In your example:

```
tar zcvf - foo 2> >(tee file.log >&2) | gpg -e -r foo@bar.com -o foo.tgz.gpg
```

Your attempts don't succeed because the piping (|) only forwards `stdout` of the previous command to the `stdin` of the current one. The current command (gpg) doesn't have access to the `stderr` of the previous command (`tar`). That `stderr` has already gone to its destination (your terminal, most likely).

`2> >(command )` pipes (quite literally `>()` create an unnamed, OS-level pipe underneath) `stderr` to `stdin` of `command`. Since `command` is a child process, its `stderr` (#2) descriptor will point to the same file as the `stderr` of the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when using 2> at the end of the line, you redirect only the second command (gpg) stderr. If you want (as it seems) to redirect the tar command stderr, you should add 2> logfile before the pipe, like this:

```
tar zcvf - foo 2> tar.log | gpg -e -r foo@bar.com -o foo.tgz.gpg
```